# Hierarchy grouping in SSRS Chart

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, mdx, ssrs-grouping, ssrs-2016

I have a problem with hierarchy grouping in SSRS StackedColumn chart.

I have Months/Quarters/Years in the category series and i want to add the totals for every quarter and month as a value in the chart but I can't find an option to do that.

I like to do something similar like parent-child grouping in table or matrix.

Comment: easiest way might be do to this in SQL and add it as an extra series. Post your dataset query if you need more help.

Comment: Well that's ok if I use SQL as source. The thing is I use MDX query and have no idea how to write that there :)

Comment: You should add an MDX tag to your question